# Reference ASP.NET Membership Database In Another Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am making a simple ASP.NET webpage for my school organization using VS2010.  When I choose "New Website," I see that Visual Studio already sets up a database for managing memberships.  I also have my own database (MyDatabase) that I need to use for the site, which contains information about the members of the organization (for example, email, phone-number, etc.)

I need to have a way to find out who the current logged-in user is, and allow them to edit ONLY their information (email, phone-number).

The way I have considered doing it is:
- Add a field in MyDatabase called "UserName" and use it as a sort-of foreign key from the other database.
- Get the username of the logged-in user
- Use this username for my queries For example:

```
// (PseudoCode)    
String loggedInUser = MembersDatbase.GetLoggedInUser();    
var MemberInfo = SELECT * FROM MyDatabase.Users WHERE UserName=loggedInUser;
```

-Then the logged-in user will only have access to their information.

I'm not sure about the code yet, but I could probably figure that part out.  I'm more interested in hearing if there is a better way of doing this.  I do NOT want to merge the two databases into a single database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the default database created by Website Template I would suggest to use aspnet_regsql.exe to install the membership table to your existing MyDatabase. Then instead of linking via username I would link the table using UserId field of aspnet_Users table. Check the links below:

1: [Tutorial: Install membership table in existing database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx)
. [Check the video here.](http://www.asp.net/security/videos/configuring-sql-to-work-with-membership-schemas)

2: [Link membership table to user info table](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-cs)

Comment: this breaks the whole idea of having authenticatie/authorization pluggable, something that is quite central in the Membership API

Comment: @Tim Mahy: I don't see a necessity to use two separate databases in the OP's scenario. I am not sure what you exactly meant by 'break'.

Comment: it's a provider-configurable-API, by using implementation details of a particular implementation (SQLServer default implementation), the whole provider-configurable part is thrown away

Comment: @Tim Mahy: OP wants to link his existing table with membership table via a FK relationship. In that case both the tables needs to be in the same database. Yes, if there was no linking then the two DBs will work without any issues. And following the way I suggested above actually will need to configure the provider to point to the existing DB instead of default created database. So still I don't get it how the 'provider-configurable part is thrown away'?

Answer (score 1):

I would use that approach, but I would use the ProviderUserKey and ProviderName property values to map to a user in your database..

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a similar approach in my application. I have a separate DB for Membership and when saving additional data about a user I just get the ProviderUseKey and save it in a separate table that contains additional user data.

Here is the sample code:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Register(string userName, string email, string password, string confirmPassword)
    {
        ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;

        if (ValidateRegistration(userName, email, password, confirmPassword))
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            var createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(userName, password, email);


            switch (createStatus)
            {
                case MembershipCreateStatus.Success:
                    FormsAuth.SignIn(userName, false /*createPersistentCookie */);
                    var userInfo = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(userName);
                    if (userInfo != null)
                    {
                        if (userInfo.ProviderUserKey != null)
                        {
                            var regularUser = new RegularUser { UserName = userInfo.UserName, Email = userInfo.Email, ProviderUserKey = userInfo.ProviderUserKey.ToString() };
                            _regularUserRepository.SaveOrUpdate(regularUser);
                        }
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
                    break;
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View();
    }
```

Hope this helps.